# 2 blocks with overflow:scroll inside each other

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have recreated my problem in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-microservice-4rplf

I'm using custom modal and custom select. Right now I have a problem ,when I open select, it unfolds inside my modal and scroll shows up.

[image]

I want to display select over my modal , like in the picture below. I achieved this result by removing overflow:auto . But I need to leave this property in case modal gets bigger. Does anyone have an idea why this happening and how to fix it ?

[image]

```
.modal-block {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 60% !important;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: You can put the content who gets bigger and the dropdown in two separate divs inside the modal. Than but the overflow scroll and max-height on the the not dropdown div. And remove overflow on modal-block.

Comment: remove the `overflow:scroll` `.modal-block`

Comment: @sumeshsn1 I cant remove overflow:scroll, I need to leave it

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS `modal.scss`

```
.modal-block {
  width: 60% !important;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-height: 400px;
   overflow-y: auto;
  .pay-form {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lovelace-52mlg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: could you please check sandbox again . Still doesn't work, I can't add overflow-y: auto;  to  .modal-body

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with css because child elements won't come out of the parent element even if you set the z-index to a higher number.

My solution is to use another modal inside the original modal. You can put your select element in the inner modal and in the outer modal just give a button at the bottom that looks like the select element and opens the inner modal on click.

You have to maintain separate state property for the inner modal.

Something like this:

```js
export default class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: true,
    isSelectOpen: true
  };

  toggleCheckbox(key) {
    console.log(key);
    this.setState({ isChecked: key });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.isChecked);
    return (
      <span className='group-block-wrapper'>
        <Modal
          title='Modal title'
          isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
          onOk={() => {}}
          onClose={() => console.log("yoy")}
          okText='pay'
        >
          he following is a guest post by Agop Shirinian.........
          <Modal
            isOpen={this.state.isSelectOpen}
            onOk={() => {}}
            onClose={() => console.log("yoy")}
            okText='Ok'
          >
            <Select
              title='select'
              options={selectOptions}
              onchange={idx => console.log(idx)}
            />
          </Modal>
        </Modal>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```